# What does "Term" on a quote mean?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I recently requested a quote from a web hosting provider. In the quote details, below the quote id number and the validity expiration date, I can read "Term - 6 months".

What does it mean? Is it a period of engagement or some other sort of commitment for me?

Comment: Length of the contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a usage of 'term' in the sense of *duration* (e.g. the *term of a loan* or a *term of office*), or where [Merriam-Webster defines it](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/term) as *a limited or definite extent of time; especially the time for which something lasts: duration, tenure*.

So, yes, it seems to suggest a period of commitment or validity for the process that you are investigating.